# Why the ring of integers of $ \mathbb Q(\sqrt{-19}) $ is $ \mathbb Z\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}{2}\right] $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Why the [ring of integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_integers) of $ \mathbb Q(\sqrt{-19}) $ is $ \mathbb Z\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}{2}\right] $?

I came up with this question when I was trying to understand this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3086739/549397. And this result seemed to be mentioned in an algebraic number theory book when I was looking for references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $d\equiv1\pmod 4$ is squarefree, then the ring of integers of $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt d)$ is ${\cal O}_K=\Bbb Z[\frac12(1+\sqrt d)]$. Pretty much every textbook
on algebraic number theory proves this.

For
$$r+s\sqrt d\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt d)$$ to be an algebraic integer, it
is necessary and sufficient for its trace
$$(r+\sqrt d)+(r-\sqrt d)=2r$$
and norm
$$(r+\sqrt d)(r-\sqrt d)=r^2-ds^2$$
to be integers. If $r$ is an integer, then from the norm being an integer
it follows that $s$ is. But if $2r$ is an odd integer, then
$(2r)^2-d(2s)^2\equiv0\pmod 4$ from which $2s$ must be an odd integer too.